# Keras training with validation data displays multiple progress bars and losses per epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using `Keras '2.2.4'` and `TensorFlow '1.13.1'` and training a MobileNetV2 on a dataset of images with 2 classes.

When I `fit` the model on both train-set and validation-set I get two distinct progress bars and multiple losses.

````
history = model.fit(
    data.flow(train_x,train_y,batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_x)//BS,
    validation_data=(val_x, val_y),
    validation_steps=len(val_x)//BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)```

Epoch 1/10
153/153 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.0134 - acc: 1.0000
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 202ms/step - loss: 0.1543 - acc: 0.9859 - val_loss: 0.0130 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/10
153/153 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.0026 - acc: 1.0000
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 194ms/step - loss: 0.0590 - acc: 0.9803 - val_loss: 0.0026 - val_acc: 1.0000
````

While if I don't add `validation_data=...` to `model.fit`:

```
history = model.fit(
    data.flow(train_x,train_y,batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_x)//BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)

Epoch 1/10
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 186ms/step - loss: 0.0404 - acc: 0.9887
Epoch 2/10
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 187ms/step - loss: 0.0189 - acc: 0.9944
Epoch 3/10
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 189ms/step - loss: 0.0137 - acc: 0.9972
```

I get only one progress bar that obviously won't show validation loss and metrics.

My question is: why? I remember that usually only one progress bar is shown with both train and validation loss and metrics. What is the that second progress bar shown in the first example?

Comment: Just a guess, what happens if instead of fit you use fit_generator? I mean maybe it happens because your training set is a generator and your validation set isn't

Comment: @MahmoudYoussef Even in tensorflow 1.13 and keras 2.2.4?

Comment: @OrpheeFaucoz Right sorry I didn't notice the version.

Comment: I mean you may be right, but I don't know. Anyway I would say the problem lie on the different data wrapper between flowed training set and  val set